# docker-compose ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a .Net Core project that I want to deploy production environment but when I try to build it on my droplet I get this error "*ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile*". I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my configurations.

**Project Structure**

```
project
│   project.sln
│   docker-compose.dcproj  
│   docker-compose.dev.yml
│   docker-compose.prod.yml 
│   docker-compose.yml
│
└───project.Web
│   │   (mvc-files)
│   │   .dockerignore
│   │   Dockerfile
│   │   project.Web.csproj
│   │
│   
└───project.Models
│
└───project.Services
│
└───project.Core
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY project.Web/project.Web.csproj project.Web/
COPY project.Models/project.Models.csproj project.Models/
COPY project.Services/project.Services.csproj project.Services/
COPY project.Core/project.Core.csproj project.Core/
RUN dotnet restore project.Web/project.Web.csproj
COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/project.Web
RUN dotnet build project.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish project.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.Web.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: project.Web/Dockerfile
```

I execute these codes on different environments

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d --build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build
```

This docker-compose works on local environment but doesn't work on prod, can't find Dockerfile.
I've checked .dockerignore if it contains Dockerfile but i doesn't.
I've tried to execute with these configs but still no luck

```
 - context: .
   dockerfile: project.Web/Dockerfile

 - context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile

 - context: app/
   dockerfile: Dockerfile

 - context: app/project.Web/
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

***EDIT:***
I didn't think dev or prod docker-compose file is the problem but adding anyway.

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  network-dev:
    driver: bridge

services:
  webapp:
    image: project
    container_name: container-webapp
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    networks:
      - "network-dev"
    ports:
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - "db"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: container-db
    environment: 
      - "POSTGRES_USER=username"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=projectdb"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "13650:5432"
    networks:
      - "network-dev"
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  network-prod:
    driver: bridge

services:
  webapp:
    image: alicoskun/project:latest
    container_name: container-webapp
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    networks:
      - "network-prod"
    ports:
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - "db"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: container-db
    environment: 
      - "POSTGRES_USER=username"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=projectdb"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "13650:5432"
    networks:
      - "network-prod"
```

Comment: Have you tried to provide an absolute path to Dockerfiles? My first guess is that `docker-compose`  on your prod env is being executed under different relative path hence this error.

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur No, I don't know the absolute path of my docker image on the droplet. Is there any way to learn it?

Comment: Please provide the content of ```docker-compose.dev.yml``` and ```docker-compose.prod.yml```.

Comment: @SteveBoyd I added both files.

Comment: Have you confirmed that both ```dev``` and ```prod``` configurations both work on your local machine?

Comment: @SteveBoyd I get the same error when I pulled and built on the cloud version. (alicoskun/project:latest). But dev version works fine because of Dockerfile is already there. (project.Web/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already pushed the `alicoskun/project:latest` image into a repository where your production droplet can find it, you have no need to include the `docker-compose.yml` file as part of your `docker-compose` command. Instead, just run:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build
```

Including the `docker-compose.yml` in your `docker-compose` command-line will require that the `Dockerfile` be present, even though it will not be used to build the system.

Comment: Removing `-f docker-compose.yml` command is worked! Thank you so much, I've been trying to get this command work for three days, I didn't know it wasn't necessary.